# How to add twitter metatags dynamically in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, seo, metadata, next.js13

I am using **Next.js 13** and using the **generateMetaData** function for **dynamic metadata** works for openGraph, but how to do it for **Twitter** meta tags?

```
export async function generateMetadata( {params, searchParams}: Props, parent?: ResolvingMetadata): Promise<Metadata> {
  return {
    openGraph: {
      type: "website",
      url: '',
      title: '',
      description: '',
      image: '',
    }
  }
}
```

For instance, the HTML output needs to be:

```
  <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
  <meta property="twitter:url" content={url} />
  <meta property="twitter:title" content={ogTitle} />
  <meta property="twitter:description" content={ogDescription} />
  <meta property="twitter:image" content={ogImage} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something very similar for twitter:

```
  twitter: {
    card: "summary_large_image",
    title: "Your title",
    description: "Your description",
    creator: "@author_name",
    images: ["you_url_here"],
  },
```

Don't forget that the recommended dimensions are 1200x630px.

More info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#twitter

Also if you end up having issues with the title / description being rendered but not the image, you might want to use this way to specify the information for the image:

```
  twitter: {
    card: "summary_large_image",
    title: "Your title",
    description: "Your description",
    creator: "@author_here",
    images: [
      {
        url: "you_url_here",
        blurDataURL: "you_blured_url_here",
        width: 1200,
        height: 630,
        alt: "Your alt text",
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: This is not working for me with Next 13

Comment: hey, what if that image is not 1200 * 630. Does just putting that width there just make it work? For a larger image for example

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you are using this function in the page.js file of the page that you like to share , or write it in app.jsx if you are sharing your whole website and want media to be rendered , I have added tag generation for whatsapp as well.

To make sure if your metatags are working fine , you can view source of your page and then check if the tags / OG tags are there or not . To view source of your page press ( Ctrl + U ) on the page that you are going to share , or you can use this validatior for twitter to see if you have a valid card ,[twitter validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) , just paste your page url and see in logs if there is green text or red. green text means you are probably doing things the right way.

```js
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  let post = await fetch(
    `https://@yourapiendpoint`,
    { cache: "no-store" } // so that we dont see stale data 
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  const twitterCard = "summary";

  return {
    openGraph: {
      title: post?.data?.title,
      description: post?.data?.description,
      url: `post/${post?.data?.postId}`,
      siteName: "your site name",
      images: [{ url: post?.data?.url, width: 1200, height: 630 }], //make sure its a valid image url
    },
    twitter: {
      card: twitterCard,
      title: post?.data?.title,
      description: post?.data?.description,
      images: [{ url: post?.data?.url, width: 1200, height: 630 }],
    },
    whatsApp: {
      title: post?.data?.title,
      description: post?.data?.description
        ?.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "")
        ?.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " "),
      thumbnailUrl: post?.data?.url,
      thumbnailWidth: 800,
      thumbnailHeight: 800,
    },
  };
}
```